# Copying trendine equation not working properly

Tags: excel, copy-paste, equation, trendline, vba

I would like to loop through four sets of data arranged in rows. I'd like to make a chart from each dataset and apply a trendline, let excel show the equation of the trendline and copy the "m" part of the equation of the trendline (y=mx+b) in a cell after the end of the row. I recorded a macro while doing the whole process with the first dataset and modified it a little to introduce the loop. My problem is that though the code creates the four charts with the trendlines and equations, but it copies the "m" value of the first chart after all the four lines. I tried to fix the problem, but failed. Now - in the same form, so I guess that it was the oroginal problem - this code prints after each dataset the first row of whatever is copied to the clipboarb from the code and after all the four datasets, and the remaining part of the copied part under it (only once). 
It might seem to make no sense, so it is best to try this code in the following way: Fill the range C3:K6 with numbers and run the code. After, copy the code to the clipboard and run the code again.
So, my thwo questions are: 1. How to make the code to copy the "m" value of each dataset after them and 2. Why does it behave so crazy now?

```
Sub Lasttest()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 6
  Range("C" & i).Select
  ActiveCell.Range("A1:I1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
  ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
  ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveCell.Range("Sheet1!A1:I1")
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).Select
  Selection.DisplayEquation = True
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
Next

End Sub
```

Ferenc

Comment: Share your code. We can tell you why your code is acting a certain way without seeing your code.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, it was left. I edited my question to include the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some code cleanup and this works for me:

```
    Sub InsertChartsAndPrintEquations()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    For i = 3 To 6
      Set rng = Range("C" & i & ":K" & i)

      ' insert chart
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
      With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Trendlines.Add
            .Trendlines(1).DisplayRSquared = False
            .Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True
        End With

        ' grab & insert equation
        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i - 2)
            .Activate
            Range("M" & i) = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
        End With
      End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Apparently, you have to use a range object when defining the source data and you have to activate the chart before you can grab the equation from it.

**Edit #1**

This code should be more robust:

```
Sub InsertChartsAndPrintEquations2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    ' add charts
    For i = 3 To 10
      Set rng = Range("C" & i & ":K" & i)
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

      With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Trendlines.Add
            .Trendlines(1).DisplayRSquared = False
            .Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True
        End With
      End With
    Next

    ' grab & insert equations
    i = 3 ' set to same starting value as in the for next loop above
    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        cht.Activate
        Range("M" & i) = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next cht

End Sub
```

Comment: as far as I can tell, you _don't_ need to Activate the Chart to get the equation.

Comment: @ chris neilsen Well, I tried without it and it didn't work, but I'm happy to concede it does sound strange.

Comment: Interesting... i did of course try it before posting that, works without for me (on Excel 365)

Comment: @ chris neilsen Did you populate C3:K6 with numbers as the OP suggested? And are you getting the equation for each row if you comment out `.Activate`? If I do that I only get one equation, not 4. (I'm on the same Excel version as you btw).

Comment: Checking it again I'm getting some really weird and inconsistent behavior. Including different result between running the code (F5) and single stepping (F8)

Comment: @ chris neilsen This sort of thing is not that unusual when working with charts in Excel in my experience. I've seen a lot of things that were seemingly weird and inconsistent compared to normal Excel behavior. I suppose this is an area of Excel which leaves of lot to be desired and MS might consider improving in future versions.

Comment: @ Miqi 180 Thank you, it works. However, I do not know how to costumize the code. When I copy the range of numbers a few rows lower (C12:K15) and change the numbers in the for loop accordingly, it returns an error message from this row:    "With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i - 2)" How to modify it?

Comment: @ Miqi 180 Thank you very much! I tested it and it works great!